# CSS/jQuery animation positioning issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I've been testing an animation using CSS transitions and jQuery. The idea is that the user is shown a set of clickable divs to load a new page. Once a div is clicked it is expanded to fill the whole screen and 'load' the next page.

Below is a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The way I set it up was to have each of the divs positioned relatively and float left to sit next to eachother. Then once a div is clicked I 'faded out' the divs apart the one that wasn't clicked and expand the clicked div. The problem was that when div clicked wasn't the first one (i.e. blue or green) it would end up 'snapping' to the left hand side before expanding. Of course this would happen since the positioning was set to relative.

```
position: relative;
```

Example of this can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKynL

To solve this issue I set up the divs with absolute positioning. The animation worked perfectly as I wanted, however I'm not liking the fact that due to the absolute positioning I have to position the left and top of every div separately plus divs will not automatically move to a new row when the window is resized.

```
position: absolute;
```

Example of this can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jIqcL

I'm not sure if there's any way I could change my implementation to improve it and make it more maintainable (particularly the inline style for the divs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your `position:relative;` (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKynL) as the source:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mydiv').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      var clicked_div = $(this);
      clicked_div.addClass('clicked');
      clicked_div.find('h1').fadeOut(150);

      $('.mydiv').not('.clicked').addClass('hide'); //<----CHANGED LINE
      clicked_div.addClass('animate');

      $('.loading').css('opacity', 1);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.mydiv').not('.clicked').css('display','none'); //<----NEW LINE
        $('.loading').css('opacity', 0);
        clicked_div.addClass('blog-post');
        clicked_div.find('h1').fadeIn(150);
        $('.blog-content').addClass('active');
      }, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, left 0.5s, top 0.5s, opacity 0.25s; /*<----ADDED 'opacity'*/
}
.mydiv h1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.teal {
  background-color: teal;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

/*-----NEW CODE---------------------------------*/
.mydiv.hide {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
/*----------------------------------------------*/

.mydiv.animate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mydiv.blog-post {
  width: 50%;
}

.blog-content {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transition: top 0.5s;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.blog-content.active {
  top: 0%;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv">
  <h1>Green</h1>
</div>
<div class="mydiv teal">
  <h1>Teal</h1>
</div>
<div class="mydiv orange">
  <h1>Orange</h1>
</div>

<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
<div class="blog-content">
  Content
</div>
```

**codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lFIhH**

---

In **CSS**, I only added this:

```
.mydiv {
  ...
  transition: ..., opacity 0.25s;
}

.mydiv.hide {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And in **JS**,

I changed this line: 
`$('.mydiv').not('.clicked').fadeOut(150, function() {` 
to 
`$('.mydiv').not('.clicked').addClass('hide');`

and added this line in the setTimeout-function:

`$('.mydiv').not('.clicked').css('display','none');`

---

**It works as follows:**

1. At the same time as the clicked `div` gets the `.animate`-class, the not-clicked `divs` get a `.hide`-class.
2. Now, as the clicked `div` is animating to fill the page, the other `divs` are animating to disappear (using `width`/`height` and `opacity`).

   - The `width`/`height` of all `divs` transition with the same speed, so as the clicked `div` grows, the other `divs` shrink, and the clicked `div` won't snap to the left/top.
   - The `opacity` of the not-clicked `divs` transitions a little faster (0.25s) to create the (seemingly) same result as in your original codepen (i.e. the not-clicked divs disappear before the clicked div expands).
3. Finally (in the setTimeout-function), for the not-clicked `divs`, `display` is set to `none`, to complete the manual fade-out.

Comment: Awesome stuff thanks for the explanation :) I knew my code was good, just a few pieces needed ironing out :) thanks a lot. I just added `height: 0px` to the `.hide` class just in case the `.mydiv` is in another row :)

Comment: Glad to help. And yes, your code is good, I learned something new from it myself. And good call on the `height`, I've added it to the answer